# WCF endpoints which work regardless of having a / at the end or not?

Tags: c#, wcf, endpoint, base-address

Ok so I have configured my WCF service and its all running fine.

Just one quirk that I cant figure out.

I have defined my base address:
eg. `<add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/EOSS/"/>`

Now if I use `http://localhost:8000/EOSS/` it works fine. However if I drop the / to `http://localhost:8000/EOSS` it doesn't work.

Is there any way to get both to work?

Comment: Does this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751515.aspx

Comment: Why do you want this, anyway?

Comment: No other reason than to see if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163412.aspx
"You can supply one base address per transport when constructing a ServiceHost object"

that means that if you want both to work you will need to add another transport with another base address